# white screen shows while scroll down /up the

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cordova, listview

We get the data from server[image: first image show when scroll up/down after that few sec show second image] and append list view .our problem is while scroll up/down first it shows white screen then after shows data. 
while scroll down/up the  before coming white screen should remove

```
for (var i=0; i<len1; i++){
     if (!listCreated) {
         $("#ulcontent").append("<ul id='content' data-role='listview'  data-split-icon='plus' data-split-theme='b' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'></ul>");  
                  var listCreated = true;
                            $("#ulcontent").trigger("create");
     }
     var geImage=result.rows.item(i).Image;
     var Custimage="";
         if(geImage)
        {
         Custimage=result.rows.item(i).Image;
         }
$('#content').append('<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child"><img src='+appendurl+append+Custimage+'><p style="white-space: normal;"><b>Location:</b>'+result.rows.item(i).Location+'<br><b> Description:</b>'+ result.rows.item(i).Comments+'</p></a></li>');
}
```

When we remove images it's not showing any white screen.But we need image 
Please tell to us what wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The`listCreated` variable in the `if (!listCreated)` statement and the `listCreated` variable in the `var listCreated = true;` statement are two different variables, so `if (!listCreated)` is always going to return `false`. That means means you're never actually creating the unordered list and then the list items are just getting displayed on the page background. So try moving `listCreated` to the outer scope like this:

```
var listCreated = false;
for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    if (!listCreated) {
        $("#ulcontent").append("<ul id='content' data-role='listview'  data-split-icon='plus' data-split-theme='b' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'></ul>");
        listCreated = true;
        $("#ulcontent").trigger("create");
    }
    var geImage = result.rows.item(i).Image;
    var Custimage = "";
    if (geImage) {
        Custimage = result.rows.item(i).Image;
    }
    $('#content').append('<li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child"><img src=' + appendurl + append + Custimage + '><p style="white-space: normal;"><b>Location:</b>' + result.rows.item(i).Location + '<br><b> Description:</b>' + result.rows.item(i).Comments + '</p></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: iam trying to above code but no use above  code also please help me